# Listing files from subdirectories in vb into cells in excel with hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

Listing files from a directory in an excel sheet? and adding hyperlinks to the results.

Added 
"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
            strTopFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
             Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
"

This enabled used selection from a top directory.

Sub ListFiles()

```
    'Set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime by using
    'Tools > References in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String

    'Insert the headers for Columns A through F
    Range("A1").Value = "File Path"
    Range("B1").Value = "File Size"
    Range("C1").Value = "File Type"
    Range("D1").Value = "Date Created"
    Range("E1").Value = "Date Last Accessed"
    Range("F1").Value = "Date Last Modified"
    Range("G1").Value = "Original Document Date" 

    'Assign the top folder to a variable
    strTopFolderName = "Y:\master-documentation" 'want to be user selectable!

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the top folder
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

    'Call the RecursiveFolder routine
    Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)

    'Change the width of the columns to achieve the best fit
    Columns.AutoFit

End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _
    IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim NextRow As Long

    'Find the next available row
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = objFile.Path
        Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = objFile.Size
        Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = objFile.Type
        Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = objFile.DateCreated
        Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        Cells(NextRow, "F").Value = objFile.DateLastModified
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next objFile

    'Loop through files in the subfolders
    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't look like `vb.net` code.

Comment: there is no question there and no problem statement, just a code dump (with a wrong tag)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of your question, but to select a folder, from Excel, you can use this code:

```
    Dim sTopFolderName As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Select Base Directory"
        If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
        sTopFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
```

Comment: Just looking for a way of selecting the directory for VB to list the files from in excel.

Comment: How does your desire differ from the results of the code snippet I posted? Selecting a **folder** is the same as selecting a **directory**

Comment: @GaryWellock Code snippet modifed a bit to simplify it

Answer (score 0):

```
'Force the explicit delcaration of variables
'Option Explicit

Sub Auto_Open()
Worksheets("Files").Columns(1).ClearContents
Worksheets("Files").Activate

    'Set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime by using
    'Tools > References in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
            strTopFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
            Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    If strTopFolderName = "" Then Exit Sub

    'Insert the headers for Columns A through G
    Range("A1").Value = "File Path"
    'Range("B1").Value = "File Name"
    'Range("C1").Value = "File Size"
    'Range("D1").Value = "File Type"
    'Range("E1").Value = "Date Created"
    'Range("F1").Value = "Date Last Accessed"
    'Range("G1").Value = "Date Last Modified"

    'Assign the top folder to a variable
    'strTopFolderName = "R:\RA\DM\Labetalol Tab\Dos\100+200mg\NP_BE"

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the top folder
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

    'Call the RecursiveFolder routine
    Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)

    'Change the width of the columns to achieve the best fit
    'Columns.AutoFit

End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _
    IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim NextRow As Long

    'Find the next available row
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = objFile.Path
        'Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = objFile.Name
        'Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = objFile.Size
        'Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = objFile.Type
        'Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = objFile.DateCreated
        'Cells(NextRow, "F").Value = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        'Cells(NextRow, "G").Value = objFile.DateLastModified
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next objFile

    'Loop through files in the subfolders
    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

This is exactly what we wanted to do! With a selection box for which directories to look at.